Adjoint of Cartan's magic formula
It is well-known that if $X$ is a vector field and $\omega$ is a form, then we have Cartan's "magic" formula
$$ L_X \omega = d\iota_X \omega + \iota_X d\omega. $$
Assuming that we are on a (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold, I would like to obtain an "adjoint" formula for the codifferential. It is also known that
$$ \langle \iota_X \omega, \eta \rangle = \langle \omega, X^\flat \wedge \eta \rangle, $$
so if we apply $\langle\langle \eta, \cdot \rangle\rangle$ (here I am taking the $L^2$ inner product and assuming the forms are compactly supported) to Cartan's formula, we get
$$ \langle\langle L_X \omega, \eta \rangle\rangle = \langle\langle \omega, X^\flat \wedge d^*\eta + d^*(X^\flat \wedge \eta) \rangle\rangle. $$
For the left-hand side, we can write
\begin{align*}
\langle L_X \omega, \eta \rangle &= -\langle \omega, L_X \eta \rangle + d\langle \omega,\eta\rangle(X) - (L_Xg)(\omega,\eta) \\
&= -\langle \omega, L_X \eta + \text{div}(X)\eta \rangle - \text{div}(\langle\omega,\eta\rangle X) - (L_Xg)(\omega,\eta).
\end{align*}
The divergence in the second term will die after integration, but how do I deal with the last term?

I found a better way using the Hodge star:
$$ \langle\langle L_X\omega, \eta \rangle\rangle = \int L_X \omega \wedge *\eta = \int L_X(\omega \wedge *\eta) - \int \omega \wedge L_X (*\eta) $$
Now
$$ \int \omega \wedge L_X (*\eta) = \langle\langle \omega, *^{-1} L_X * \eta \rangle\rangle, $$
while
\begin{align*}
\int L_X(\omega \wedge *\eta) 
&= \int L_X(\langle \omega,\eta\rangle v_g) =
\int d\langle \omega,\eta\rangle(X)\, v_g + \int \langle \omega,\eta \rangle L_X v_g \\
&= \int \text{div}(\langle\omega,\eta\rangle X) v_g - \int \langle \omega, \eta \rangle \text{div}X \, v_g + \int \langle\omega,\eta\rangle \text{div} X \,v_g \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
So
$$ \langle\langle L_X\omega, \eta \rangle\rangle = -\langle\langle \omega, *^{-1} L_X * \eta \rangle\rangle, $$
using which one sees that
$$ X^\flat \wedge d^*\eta + d^* (X^\flat \wedge \eta) = -*^{-1} L_X * \eta. $$
